# fancybox.js , missing sprites, unusual photo behavior for Rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

If anyone is familiar with [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net) maybe you can help me solve a couple of issues I am having:

First, when I click on an image the image in the background disappears. If I keep clicking on images eventually all the images disappear.

The other issue I am having is that the prev, next, sprites do not show up or work.

it should look like this but it does not:

[image]

Here is some of my code:

listing show.html.erb:

```
<div class="span4">


<% @listing.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
          <%if index == 0 %>

              <%= image_tag image.file, :class => "thumbnail"%>

          <%elsif index == 1%>
            <ul class="thumbnails small">               
              <li class="span4">
                <%= image_tag image.file, :class => "thumbnail"%>
              </li>                                 

          <%elsif index ==2%> 
              <li class="span4">
                <%= image_tag image.file, :class => "thumbnail"%>
              </li> 
          <%elsif index ==3%> 
              <li class="span4">
                <%= image_tag image.file, :class => "thumbnail"%>
              </li>
          <%else%> 
          </ul>          
          <%end%>        

        <% end %> 
      </div>
```

jquery.fancybox.css.scss

```
#fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
    background-image: url('fancybox_sprite.png');
}
```

listing.js.cofee

```
$ ->
  $("#myTab a:first").tab "show"
  $("#myTab a").click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab "show"


$(document).ready ->
  $(".thumbnail").fancybox
    openEffect: "none"
    closeEffect: "none"

  $(".carousel").carousel interval: false
```

The fancybox javascript file css files I am using are [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beamon/u96xZ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are binding fancybox to the `<img />` tags through the `class="thumbnail"` so they are treated like ***inline*** content (inline content has set `display:none;` when is returned to its position in the document's flow when closing fancybox)

What you have to do is to wrap your images inside an anchor `<a>` tag AND set the `class="thumbnail"` to that anchor, so instead of having this (rendered html)

```
<img class="thumbnail" src="images/01.jpg" alt="" />
```

...your should have this :

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="images/01.jpg" rel="gallery"><img src="thumbs/01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Regarding the `prev`, `next` and `close` icons, make sure that the `fancybox_sprite.png` file is located on the same directory as the fancybox css file

Comment: thanks for the help. Everything works except for the fancybox-next and fancybox-prev. The fancybox-close works and is rendering the sprite. Any idea why? Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: I guess you also need to add `rel="gallery"` to each anchor to create the gallery (so next/prev navigation arrows will appear)... see my edited answer